# Simultaneous searching of multiple words in an external file(Java)

Tags: java, netbeans

The program that I am trying to create is a program that takes words from a user defined file, saves those words as variables and then searches a different user defined file for those words, outputting there location.

The program works up to and including the point where the program takes the words and saves them as variables. The problem with the program is that the search method returns a null result. My main suspicions are that the code in the search method is incompatible with the code in the read method, or that the 2 methods aren't running simultaneously.

The search method is in the searching class and the read method is in the reading class.

Here is my code (Containing all 3 of my classes), please excuse all of the imports.

This is the first class:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Combination{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Reading ReadingObject = new Reading();        
    System.out.println("Please enter the file that you wish to open");
    String temp = userInput.nextLine();
    ReadingObject.setFileName(temp);
    ReadingObject.read();
    Scanner searchForWord = new Scanner(System.in);
    Searching SearchingObject = new Searching();
    System.out.println("Please enter the file that you would like to search for these words in");
    String temp1 = searchForWord.nextLine();
    SearchingObject.setFileName(temp1);
    SearchingObject.search();

}    
}
```

This is the second class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Reading {
private String file;
public void setFileName(String fileName){
    file = fileName;
}
public String getFileName(){
    return file;
}
public void read(){
    try{
        //Choosing the file to open
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(getFileName());

        //Get the object of datainputstream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine = null;

        //Read the file line by line
        while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            //      \\s+ means any number of whitespaces between tokens
            String [] tokens = strLine.split("\\s+");
            String [] words = tokens;
            for(String word : words){
                System.out.print(word);
                System.out.print(" ");

                Searching SearchingObject = new Searching();
                SearchingObject.setWord(word);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");   
        }
        in.close();  
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  
    }
}
}
```

This is the third class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Searching {
private String file1;
public void setFileName(String fileName){
    file1 = fileName;
}
public String getFileName(){
    return file1;
}
private String word1;
public void setWord(String wordName){
    word1 = wordName;    
}
public String getWord(){
    return word1;
}

public void search() throws FileNotFoundException{

    try{
        //Choosing the file to open
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(getFileName());

        //Get the object of datainputstream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine = null;

        while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(getWord());
            Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);

        int start = 0;
        while (m.find(start)) {
            System.out.printf("Word found: %s at index %d to %d.%n", m.group(), m.start(), m.end());
            start = m.end();
                }
          }        
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
}
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Follow conventions: ClasNamesStartWithCaps, variablesDoNot. They make your code easier to read.

Comment: Also, you are pasting several classes into a single code snippet. Either make several snippets, or turn the extra classes into static internal classes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am new to programming and this site. I have made adjustments accordingly except for the variable capitalization. Is the code easy to view if I lay it out with each class separate?

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text. Unfortunately examples like this get copied again and again so can you can remove it from your example. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is hard to read. Your `reading` class does not only read; it also searches. You should call it something that reflects its intended use. However, it forgets to tell its `searching` object where to search, and does not pass the reference to this object to anyone else. In this snippet

```
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.print(word);
    System.out.print(" ");

    searching searchingObject = new searching();
    searchingObject.setWord(word);
}
```

you are essentially not doing anything. The reference to `searchingObject` is lost forever.

Your `reading` class should keep an ArrayList of words to be searched for in the `searching`, instead of instancing searching objects.

Your `searching` class should take, as a constructor parameter, one of these ArrayLists -- and convert it into a single regex, which is much more efficient than reading the file once per word to search for. You can search for "a", "b" and "c" using the single regular expression "a|b|c". Works with longer words, too. Escape them first to avoid problems.

Oh, and please, please follow naming guidelines. Call your `reading` a `TokenReader`, and your `searching` a `WordListSearcher`...

Comment: If you do not need to search for complex patterns, and are only interested in exact-same-spelling words, use a HashSet<String> 's .contains(word) method instead of regular expressions. Faster and easier to read; and no problems with regular expression escapes

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Sorry about the naming guidelines, i'm new to java and everything that I know is self-taught. it was not my intention for my "reading" class to also search and I was of the opinion that by adding the searchingObject I was allowing my searching class to access the reading class. your answer does resolve my query, and I see my mistakes. Regards

Comment: Re Java: the best way to learn a programming language is to see what good developers do. In NetBeans, you can ctrl+click on *any* class name and see the source it came from. Look at the source for the standard libraries - String, System, File, ... - they are very good examples.

Comment: Programming is not easy. Don't give up, and try to break things into smaller chunks, instead of trying to solve everything in one go. Ask for *specific steps* in new questions, but only after you try them yourself.